# Have two resources and append one to another in the Chef remote_file

Tags: ruby, file, text, copy, chef-infra

I would like to copy *http://seapower/spring.txt* and *http://seapower/has_sprung.txt* and append second one to the first one in a new file named src_filepath.txt:

```
remote_file 'src_filepath.txt' do
  source 'http://seapower/spring.txt', 'http://seapower/has_sprung.txt'
  checksum node['nginx']['foo123']['checksum']
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0755'
end
```

It doesn't work and just copy the first file to src_filepath.txt

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is probably a good place to start and then tweak however you like:

```
cache1 = "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/content1"
cache2 = "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/content2"

# this will not redownload if cache1 exists and has not been updated
remote_file cache1 do
  source "http://source.url/content1"
end

# this will not redownload if cache1 exists and has not been updated
remote_file cache2 do
  source "http://source.url/content2"
end

# this will not update the file if the contents has not changed
file "/my/combined/file" do
  content lazy { IO.read(cache1) + IO.read(cache2) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not something Chef supports directly. You could use multiple `remote_file` resources and either a `ruby_block` or `execute` plus `cat` to implement the concat.

Answer (score 0):

`remote_file` does not support concatenation, so you would not be able to implement this using that resource directly, however you could piece together the desired result using the `file` resource and `Net::HTTP` like so:

```
file_path = '/path/to/your_whole_file'

unless File.exist?(file_path) &&
       Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(File.read(file_path)) == 'your_file_checksum'
  file file_path do
    content(
      Net::HTTP.get(URI('http://source.url/content1')) +
      Net::HTTP.get(URI('http://source.url/content2'))
    )
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '0755'
  end
end
```

The reason for the `Digest::SHA256` call at the beginning is to prevent Chef from trying to download both files during every Chef run. Note that you may have to require the `net/http` and `digest` gems at the top of your recipe for this to work.

Also, because it's against best practices to put Ruby code directly into your recipes, you may want to wrap the above code in a simple [custom resource](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html).

Comment: It is almost always the wrong idea to use `Net::HTTP` in Chef code. You should be using `Chef::HTTP` instead.

Comment: yeah this answer is fairly convoluted.  it'd be better to use two remote_file resources to download into the Chef::Config[:file_cache_path] and rely on chef's idempotency to not re-download on every run.  then construct a file resource where the content concatenated IO.read to the pathnames the remote_fille resources use.

Comment: Point taken about it being convoluted (although I'd argue that the request is a fairly specific one), but why is calling `IO.read` any better than calling `Net::HTTP` (or `Chef::HTTP`)?